# Calculate cumsum for each factor

Tags: r

I want to calculate the cumsum by the factor key. In detail, if you would split the vector time by the factor key, calculate the the cumsum of `1:length(subvector)`. But I like to do it for the whole vector, so that I dont lost the relation to the index.

```
a<-as.POSIXlt("2013-07-01 00:00:00",origin = "1960-01-01",tz="GMT")
b<-as.POSIXlt("2013-07-08 00:00:00",origin = "1960-01-01",tz="GMT")
week1<-sample(seq(as.numeric(a),by=60*60,length.out=200),200,T)
week2<-sample(seq(as.numeric(b),by=60*60,length.out=200),200,T)
times<-c(week1,week2)
class(times)<-c("POSIXt","POSIXct")
times<-as.POSIXlt(times,origin = "1960-01-01",tz="GMT")
key<-sample(LETTERS[1:3],200,T)
df<-data.frame(times=times,order=factor(rep(1:2,each=100)), key=key)
```

And with that there comes an other problem how to make a point-plot with x-axis=time and y-axis=new_cumsum_vector and additionaly to collect y values in intervals. So that for an interval on x-axis there is a y-coordinate which represents the sum of all entrys in new_cumsum_vector for each key.

Answer (score 0):

Are you l0oking for this?

```
library(plyr)
df$times<-as.Date(times,format="%Y-%m-%d")
mysum<-ddply(df,.(times,key),summarize,msum=sum(as.numeric(order)))
> head(mysum)
       times key msum
1 2013-07-01   A   12
2 2013-07-01   B   15
3 2013-07-01   C   13
4 2013-07-02   A    9
5 2013-07-02   B   15
6 2013-07-02   C   16
```

Comment: No because you you split it by key and by the variable order. And the interval should be flexible. And I need the relation to the indecies for plotting, that means I need a vector of length df[,1].

Comment: Ok. Then, you probably need to update the question with the expected output

Comment: It's straight forward to what I was discribing `s<-split(df,df$key)

for(i in 1:length(s)){
  a<-cumsum(1:length(s[[i]][,1]))
  s[[i]]$new<-a
}
do.call("rbind",s)` but I dont want a step by step solution. And I see there is a little mistake what I ment is `s<-split(df,df$key)

for(i in 1:length(s)){
  a<-(1:length(s[[i]][,1]))
  s[[i]]$new<-a
}
do.call("rbind",s)`

Comment: Yes, it's straightforward. But, I need to see whether my results match with yours.